# ~/.ssh/known_hosts file - how to set it up?

Tags: ssh, scp, known-hosts

I'm trying to SCP a file from my server to another server. The command I'm using is:

```
scp -i private.ppk -P 22 foo.txt someuser@domain.com:/home/someuser/foo.txt
```

When I run this via the command line, I get prompted:

```
The authenticity of host 'domain.com' can't be established.
RSA fingerprint is: ...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Since I need to do this via PHP (and not the command line), I can't be bothered by these prompts. I think I need to set something in the known_hosts_file to prevent this prompt. Is that correct? If so, how do I do that? How do I set up my server's known_hosts_file so that I don't get prompted?

Comment: @EEAA I don't see how these questions are to be equal.

Comment: Have you never used ssh before?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asked just once. You can copy the respective entry from the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file to the same file for other users. Or you put it into `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` then it's valid for all users.